# Best Spring API for developing GenericDao

Tags: spring, spring-data, genericdao, spring-data-jpa

I see lot of implementation technique about spring jpa(**jpatemplate,japdaosupport spring-data-jpa ,native way entitymanager,HibernateSupport,ect** ),which one is best technique for developing Generic DAO ,that should be clean resource allocation ,transaction management , and high performance .
what are pros and cons

**scenario**

- entity >70
- web app and webservices
- future osgi support and multiple data sources

Comment: It depends :D! What is a GenericDao for you?

Comment: for save,update,delete,findByID,findAll(paging),findByQuery,findByNamedQuery ,etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way would be to stick to the @PersistentContext to handle instances of EntityManagers, and inject them into some third party generic dao. You could write one on your own, use spring-data as mentioned by @Ralph or try libraries like [Hades](http://redmine.synyx.org/projects/show/hades).

Answer (score 1):

Spring-data-jpa comes with an already compleate GenericDao (with all the stuff you mentiond), but as far as I know you will need at least a (empty) interface for each concrete dao.